# How do I fix this error: Permission denied - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/city-state-0.0.13/lib/db/states.us

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rubygems

Right now, I am currently working on a Customer project on Ruby on Rails that asks for information such as Username, First Name, Last Name, Street 1, Street 2, City and State. In this project, the City and State should be select boxes with populated entries from the city-state gem.

I typed `gem 'city-state'` in my Gemfile then run `bundle install` in the terminal (Mac OS).

Now in my form file, `_form.html.erb`:

```
<%= form_for(@customer) do |f| %>
    <% if @customer.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(@customer.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this customer from being saved:</h2>

          <ul>
            <% @customer.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
                <li><%= message %></li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :username %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :username %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :first_name %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :last_name %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :street1 %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :street1 %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :street2 %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :street2 %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :state %><br>
      <select id="states-of-country" name="state">
        <option value="" selected="">Select Your State</option>
        <% CS.states(:us).each do |key, value| %>
        <option value="&lt;%= key %&gt;"><%= value %></option>
        <% end %>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :city %><br>
      <select id="cities-of-state" name="city">
        <option value="" selected="">Select Your City</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <script>
        $('#states-of-country').change(function () {
            var input_state = $(this);
            var cities_of_state = $("#cities-of-state");

            if ($(this).val() == "") {
                cities_of_state.html("");

            } else {
                $.getJSON('/cities/' + $(this).val(), function (data {
// cities_of_state.empty();
                    var opt = '<option value="" selected="">Select Your City</option>';
                    console.log(data);
                    if (data.length == 0) {

                    } else {
                        data.forEach(function (i) {
                            opt += '<option value="+ i +">' + i + '</option>';
                            cities_of_state.html(opt);
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

The error focuses on the `CS.states(:us)` then when I run the server, everytime I go to the create or edit customer, I get this error:

> Permission denied - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/city-state-0.0.13/lib/db/states.us

PS. Before I typed `gem 'city-state'` in my gem file, I did this first in the terminal: `sudo gem install 'city-state'`

Comment: Try to run with gem install 'city-state'. and then retry and see if it works.

Comment: you should be using the `sudo` command to install your gems, unless absolutely necessary

Comment: that's exactly what i did at first. I have installed city-state already but i keep getting a Errno::EACCES error. @oreoluwa

Comment: ok. One advise though, always use a version manager, such as `rbenv` or `rvm` to manage your ruby versions. Would save you a lot of productive time

Comment: I have solved it by typing "sudo chown -R $(whoami) /Library" :)

Comment: Is there a particular constraint forcing you to modify/rely upon Ruby and Rubygems shipped with OS X? As @oreoluwa said - rbenv is a much more predictable/reliable way to go. Especially when updating versions of OS X or updating Ruby for security/patches/features.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of file permissions in system ruby and gem being installer as root. Quick fix is to `chmod`/`chown` `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/`.

But a much better way is using a ruby version manager like `rbenv` or `rvm`, so that you have a separate ruby installation. RVM even provides "gemsets" feature - so that you can have isolated gem environment for every project.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and this solution work for me:

$gem which city-state

-> /Users/macbook/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/city-state-0.0.13/lib/city-state.rb

$sudo chown -R $(whoami) /Users/macbook/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/*